# How do I install the Mono Winforms Designer on Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, winforms, macos, mono, installation

I've searched around but was unable to find a good, clear, answer. Can someone please explain to me how I can install the Mono Winforms Designer on Mac OS X? If it's not possible on OS X, can it be done on Linux? And if so, how?

Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you probably ***could*** install the Mono Winforms designer on OS X or Linux, you will quickly find that it is a very rough prototype that is not suitable for use.  Development on it was abandoned a couple of years ago.

Comment: Really? Darn. Is there any other designer for GUI applications in Mono?

Comment: MonoDevelop has a Gtk# designer, however it only runs on Linux or Windows.

Comment: jpobst: Monodevelop has come along in leaps and bounds since and your answer is, I think negative and off-putting for someone who has a Mac OSX environment... 'Development on it was abandoned a couple of years ago'...since when did you last check the site? :)

Comment: tommieb75: jpobst was referring to the Mono Winforms Designer, not MonoDevelop.

Comment: The question does not mention MD, so my answer refers to the Winforms designer.  Edited to clarify.  MD is of course, awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to use MonoDevelop for the Mac OSX. Go to [Mono.com](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:OSX) here and you will find the information on how to install it on Mac OSX. The download page for Mac OSX is [here](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html), click on the Mac OSX icon and you should be good to go after downloading the appropriate packages.

There is a caveat emptor which I'll quote from the page - ***Gtk# and System.Windows.Forms applications require X11. Installing on a machine without X11 installed will result in errors during install, and these components will not function correctly.***

I would guess it has to do with the Mac OS X's GUI conflicting with X...I'd imagine..not 100% sure.

For MonoDevelop, click [here](http://monodevelop.com/Download), click on the Mac OSX Icon..this will sit on top of the Mono framework...you will need to dig around a bit to see if this will co-exist with your existing setup... not sure here...

The good news on the Linux side, is it works, if you are building mono from scratch, using the Mono-2.6.1. sources [here](http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources-stable/), build in this order...

- mono-2.6.1.tar.bz2
- libgdiplus-2.6.1.tar.bz2
- mono-tools-2.6.1.tar.bz2
- mono-debugger-2.6.1.tar.bz2
- mono-addins-2.6.1.tar.bz2

The rest of them are optional.

**Edit:** I have added a few more bits of information. There is a cross-platform alternative to designing GUI's with Mono, it is Gtk# and Glade#. The Gtk# toolkit is a wrapper around the GTK tools that is used by Gnome. Glade# is a UI designer toolkit that uses Gtk#. This answer would not be complete without mentioning a couple of links to some tutorials on Gtk#.

- Gtk# Tutorial on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/gtksharpguide.aspx).
- [Calc#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cross-platform/calcsharp.aspx) - an intro to Gtk#
- Custom controls with Mono and Gtk# [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/static/customgtkcontrol.aspx)
- Glade code changer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GladeCodeChanger.aspx)

All of the above links reside at CodeProject.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I have MonoDevelop installed but how can I install the Winforms Designer? Or is it installed already?

Comment: What version of MonoDevelop do you have? see here for the official line on this..http://monodevelop.com/Download/What's_new_in_MonoDevelop_2.2

Comment: I have MonoDevelop 2.2. I'll take a look at the What's New page.

Comment: MonoDevelop does not have a Winforms Designer.  It has a Gtk# designer, though I think it only works on Linux and Windows, not Mac.